# boost.asio and pfring conflict

Tags: c++, linux, boost-asio

I wrote a program witch use pfring and asio,

My program like:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <pfring.h>

int main(void) {
    // ... 
    return 0;
}
```

I got error:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/pfring.h:46:0,
             from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/linux/if.h:136:8: error: redefinition of 'struct ifmap'
/usr/include/net/if.h:112:8: error: previous definition of 'struct ifmap'
/usr/include/linux/if.h:170:8: error: redefinition of 'struct ifreq'
/usr/include/net/if.h:127:8: error: previous definition of 'struct ifreq'
/usr/include/linux/if.h:219:8: error: redefinition of 'struct ifconf'
/usr/include/net/if.h:177:8: error: previous definition of 'struct ifconf'
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a conflict between boost and pfringe. The problem is explained here:

```
/usr/include/linux/if.h:136:8: error: redefinition of 'struct ifmap'
/usr/include/net/if.h:112:8: error: previous definition of 'struct ifmap'
```

It appears that the problem is being caused by a collision within the Linux headers. First, check if you have the latest Linux kernel, Linux headers, and pfringe. If not, update them. If that fails, check to see if you have any old headers lying around. If so, remove them. In Ubuntu, this can be done from the Computer Janitor application. If all else fails, try uninstalling and reinstalling pfringe. Make sure it's the appropriate version for your OS!

Answer (score 0):

The linux headers are broken. On the latest ubuntu 11.10 release with the latest kernel with no old headers lying around, the following program fails to compile. It is quite annoying when I need parts from both headers, like if_nametoindex() from net/if.h and ARPHRD_ETHER from linux/if_arp.h - So all I can do is copy/paste the definitions that I need into my source from the linux headers!!

```
#include <linux/if.h>
#include <net/if.h>

int main()
{
}
```

Errors:

```
In file included from x.c:1:0:
/usr/include/linux/if.h:178:19: error: field ‘ifru_addr’ has incomplete type
/usr/include/linux/if.h:179:19: error: field ‘ifru_dstaddr’ has incomplete type
/usr/include/linux/if.h:180:19: error: field ‘ifru_broadaddr’ has incomplete type
/usr/include/linux/if.h:181:19: error: field ‘ifru_netmask’ has incomplete type
/usr/include/linux/if.h:182:20: error: field ‘ifru_hwaddr’ has incomplete type
In file included from x.c:2:0:
/usr/include/net/if.h:45:5: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
/usr/include/net/if.h:112:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct ifmap’
/usr/include/linux/if.h:136:8: note: originally defined here
/usr/include/net/if.h:127:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct ifreq’
/usr/include/linux/if.h:170:8: note: originally defined here
/usr/include/net/if.h:177:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct ifconf’
/usr/include/linux/if.h:219:8: note: originally defined here
```

Edit: It looks like this bug has been fixed in the linux kernel package 2.6.37-4.12 now:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/+bug/673073/comments/10

But for some reason it doesn't work on my system which is linux 3.0 based. hmmm...

Answer (score 0):

I forgot a macro, add to CFLAGS -DHAVE_PCAP. It's solved. Thanks everyone